# Ancora utilizando animate.scrollTop com altura personalizada

Tags: jquery

Preciso editar a ancora do conteudo para uma altura menor do que a do conteudo.

Estou utilizando o js

```
 $(".white-felling").click(function(){
                    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:$("#white-felling").offset().top},"500");
                    return true
                })
```

e ao clicar, sou direcionado ao conteudo:

```
 <section class="text medium-12 medium-centered columns" id="white-felling">
bla bla bla
</div>
```

Mas tenho um problema, pois utilizo um header com altura fixa, assim, ao utilizar a ancora o conteudo fica oculto.

Como fica:
[image: como fica]

Como deveria ficar:
[image: como deveria ficar]

jsfindle: http://jsfiddle.net/thallysondias/n4r2ao8n/
Existe alguma forma de manter a função de ancora (com o link a exibir xxx.com#section) e mesmo assim editar a altura para menos pixeis?

Comment: Podes fazer um jsfiddle com o problema ou colocar o código em questão aqui? Senão fica dificil perceber o que pode estar a falhar

Comment: Sergio, aqui esta: http://jsfiddle.net/thallysondias/n4r2ao8n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você precisa fazer 2 coisas:

1. Mensurar a altura do header
2. Descontar o valor da altura do header no valor inteiro passado para scrollTop

Para o (1), você pode usar o Crome Dev Tools para o Google Chrome o Firebug para o Firefox ou o Internet Explorer Developer Tools, se usa o IE.

Abaixo segue um exemplo de como fazer isso no Chrome:

- Pressione F12
- Clique na lupa, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

- Mova a imagem até a área do elemento a ser mensurado (no seu caso, o header)
- Anote o valor de altura (no caso da imagem acima, 208px)

Fazendo o (2), seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
$(".white-felling").click(function(){
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#white-felling").offset().top - <valor_altura_do_header>
    },"500");
    return true
    })
```

Onde `<valor_altura_do_header>` é o valor mensurado usando o Dev Tools, no caso da imagem acima, seria 208.

Comment: André, obrigado. Eu tinha tentado fazer, estava colocando:
.top(-300)/ .top(-300px)/.top(top:-300) e sempre dava erro. O correto era tirar as aspas. Muito obrigado.